# How can I edit the url where my slack bot lives?

Tags: slack, bot, slackbot

I created a slack app/bot user which I can direct message. When I send it a message it sends me a response. The bot is deployed in heroku.

I'd like the bot to no longer live in heroku, but live somewhere else. How can I change where slack looks for my deployed bot? I don't see where in the slack UI where the bot's url location is or how I can change that url.